# shell script - edit lines in shadow file (':' delimiter)

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

In the following shadow-type file:

```
user1:*:11111:0:88888:7:::
user2:*:11111:0:88888:7:::
user3:!!:11111:0:88888:7:::
user4:!!:11111:0:88888:7:::
user5:!!:11111:0:88888:7:::
user6:!!:11111:0:88888:7:::
```

I need find user 4, for example, and replace the '!!' with 'something_else'. Does anyone know how I could do this?

EDIT: Sorry that I wasn't clear - the '!!' could be anything.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do... I can iterate through each line in a file using `while read line;do...done<"$PWD/shadow"` and replace, but that won't end up doing what I want. I also could do `sed s/user4:!!/user4:"$something_else"` but the item after `user4:` isn't always `!!`

Comment: I would highly disrecommend editing critical system files with shell scripts - I've seen way too many of them go bad and render a system unusable. Use the appropriate tools (e.g. `passwd`, etc.) to make those changes - they're much more likely to have been written to take into account disk full conditions, concurrent changes, proper syntax of the file, dependencies with other resources, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were near with your [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command. Better to use the substitution command only in the line searched, and instead of trying to match a literal use `[^...]` to match while a character not found, in this case the colon. Try:

```
sed '/^user4:/ s/:[^:]*/:something_else/' infile
```

It yields:

```
user1:*:11111:0:88888:7:::
user2:*:11111:0:88888:7:::
user3:!!:11111:0:88888:7:::
user4:something_else:11111:0:88888:7:::
user5:!!:11111:0:88888:7:::
user6:!!:11111:0:88888:7:::
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 sed '/^user4:/s/!!/something else/' file
```